# How to convert this output to json and fetch the values

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary

```
print(type(directreceipts))
print(directreceipts)
```

o/p

```
1
2
<class 'list'>

['{\n "quantityOfUnits": 1500,\n "ownerOnDespatch": "100038",\n "packSize": 3\n}', '{\n "quantityOfUnits": 2500,\n "ownerOnDespatch": "100038",\n "packSize": 4\n}']
```

want to convert the list of strings to dictionary and access the values and also want to eleminate the \n.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to try to remove `\n` here. Just parse the string with `json`.

```
import json
directreceipts = [json.loads(d) for d in directreceipts]
```

Output:

```
[{'quantityOfUnits': 1500, 'ownerOnDespatch': '100038', 'packSize': 3},
 {'quantityOfUnits': 2500, 'ownerOnDespatch': '100038', 'packSize': 4}]
```

You can access the values like,

Single-value access,

```
In [1]: directreceipts[0]['quantityOfUnits']
Out[1]: 1500
```

Ideally, iterate through and access the values

```
In [2]: for item in directreceipts:
    ...:     print(item['quantityOfUnits'])
    ...: 
1500
2500
```

To find the sum of those values, Using list comprehension.

```
In [3]: sum([item['quantityOfUnits'] for item in directreceipts])
Out[3]: 4000
```

Comment: how do i fetch the value of quantity of units here ?

Comment: how do i sum up the values which i get from the output for item in directreceipts: print(item['quantityOfUnits']) 1500 + 2500 = 4000 should be my o/p

Comment: How can i fetch only date from this 2022-10-05T07:08:55.8197232

my o/p should look like this 2022-10-05

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
list_object[0].encode("utf-8").decode()
```

or you can try this one also :

```
import json
json.loads(list_object[0])
```

Comment: No it din't work.
o/p
----

resp = directreceipts[0].encode("utf-8").decode()

AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'encode'

Comment: resp = json.loads(directreceipts[0])
 print(resp)
TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not dict